# Pivot SQL results

Tags: sql, null, numbers, pivot, row

I have a table called test:

create table test
 (time int,
  event varchar(50));

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test]
       ([time]
       ,[event])
 VALUES
       (8,'start'),
       (9,'stop'),
       (11,'start'),
       (12,'stop'),
       (null,'start')

    select No , sum(case when event ='start' then time end) start,
    sum(case when event ='stop' then time end) stop
    From
    (select ROW_NUMBER()OVER( partition by event order by time)No,time,event
    from 
    (select isnull(time,0)as time, event from [dbo].[test] )y
     )x
    group by No
```

How do I get the null value to sort in the right position in the end instead of the beginning and is there a better way to write this query?

```
The expected outcome 
 Row No  Start Stop
  1      8     9
  2      11    12
  3      Null
```

Comment: GurV..Please see the expected outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case` to move the nulls to the last.

Try this:

```
select No,
    sum(case when event = 'start' then time end) start,
    sum(case when event = 'stop' then time end) stop
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (
            partition by event order by case when time is null then 1 else 0 end,
                time
            ) No,
        time,
        event
    from (
        select time,
            event
        from @test
        ) y
    ) x
group by No
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/SSC37378)